# Extracting specific value from multiple sheets

Tags: r, list, extract, filenames, lapply

I have multiple excel files with multiple sheets. I need to extract the information from J9:Q10 of the specific sheet for each file, (J9 is empty). Row 9 is the header, Row 10 is the value.

example of needed cells

[image]

and I also need the file name as its header or index (it contains date, for example: weekly_report_2021-12-22). I already extract those value to a list

```
list <- c(list2022,list2020,list2021,list2019)


lst1 <- lapply(list, function(x) read.xlsx(x, sheet = "1", startRow = 8, cols = 11:17, rows = 9:10))
```

I tried to convert the lists to data frame as below.

```
perc <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lst1)
```

But I'm not sure how to connect the file name to each of the list.

I want something as below:
[image]

Column I is F4 in the same sheet.

Please kindly let me know if you have any idea, Thanks!

Comment: Questions are unclear. What do you mean with  "I need to extract the value from J9-Q10"? Could you add an example of this, please? Do the values follow some condition or it always have the same value? Because if this is the case you could do something like this: `subset(df, df$column == value)`. On the other hand, I don't understand the second question "I also need the file name as its header or index (it contains date)". Could you explain it better, please? Do you want to add the name of the file in your dataframe (row 1 e.g.)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I need the value of the same range/cell from each file. extract the whole column doesn't work for me since the I only need specific rows in these columns. Just added more details and examples.

Comment: Hi, did my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

In order to "recreate" your scenario, I created 3 ".xlsx" files like this:
[image: image 1]

Each file is named as: "weekly_report_[INSERT DATE].xlsx"

What you need to do is list all your files (make sure that you are in the path where you have them).

```
file.list<- list.files( pattern="weekly_report_")
file.list
[1] "weekly_report_2021-12-22.xlsx" "weekly_report_2022-08-22.xlsx" "weekly_report_2022-12-22.xlsx"
```

Then, you upload them using `lapply` and choosing the range of columns that you are interested in.

```
df.list=lapply(file.list, function(x) read_excel(x,range = "J9:Q10"))
```

You change the names of the first column with the name of the file:

```
names(df.list) <- file.list
```

Then, you merge all the files in one:

```
final_df=bind_rows(df.list, .id = "Date_Duration")
```

In order to have a proper format of the filenames, I used `gsub`:

```
final_df$Date_Duration <- gsub(".xlsx", "", final_df$Date_Duration)
final_df$Date_Duration <- gsub("weekly_report_", "", final_df$Date_Duration)
```

Finally, I remove the column "Success" that I don't want.

```
final_df <- select(final_df, -2)
```

Result:
[image]

I hope this helps.